# Is "Advances in Engineering" a predatory platform?

Tags: publications, disreputable-publishers

I have received an e-mail from "Advances in Engineering". Is it a predatory-platform? Is it reputable?

...

Dear Dr. XYZ,

We are pleased to inform you that Advances in Engineering selection committee identified your paper “Another XYZ” as a key scientific article contributing to research excellence. We would like to write a feature about your paper and highlight it in our next edition of Advances in engineering news series.

AIE highlight papers of exceptional scientific importance to a broad science and engineering audience (for the latest edition https://advancesENG.com). The feature is intended to globally disseminate research excellence across academia and in the wider community, and to inspire new research directions.

AIE reaches a global audience of 850,000 professors and scientists per month who seek the key research news and accomplishments in engineering. Papers featured at AIE gain extensive visibility and increased citations.

If you accept our special invitation, our professional writers will write a high quality feature draft about your research paper (significance of the work done) and then share it with you for final approval.

AIE is not-for-profit focused on serving research excellence. However, there is a small nominal fee for featuring key scientific articles at AIE ($75 USD total fee) to cover AIE writers’ time in preparing the feature. We can send you an official invoice and we will feature your research within 14 days.

At AIE, we highlight the researchers work at the cutting edge of science, those who are developing the innovations that will lead to a brighter tomorrow. I look forward to hearing from you.

Respectfully,

ZYX

ZYX, PhD MBA
VP Scientific affairs, Advances in Engineering

38 Auriga Drive, Suite 200. Ottawa, ON K2E 8A5, Canada

Comment: You shouldn't need to ask this question. An email that starts with "We are pleased to inform you that Advances in Engineering selection committee identified your paper 'Another XYZ' as a key scientific article contributing to research excellence." should be moved into your spam folder.

Comment: Close voters:  Explain how this is a shopping question?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist **...**  _seek an assessment_ **...**

Comment: I don't see how seeking an assessment makes this a shopping question.

Comment: @scaaahu I agree with Allure.  This question isn't "should I buy this service."  The close reasons need a bit of rewriting.  Or maybe unrewriting.

Comment: And how is this a duplicate?  The question is not about a journal.  @Wrzlprmft

Comment: @Allure: “Evaluate X for me” has all the problems that "should I buy X" has. This is one of the reasons why we put the *seeking an assessment* phrase into that close reason. Otherwise, you could rewrite every shopping into a valid one without substantially changing anything. (Also see [the FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657).)

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: I closed as a duplicate because it is pointing the asker and other visitors having the same question in the right direction. This does not make the question any less shopping. As the question assumes that the service in question is a journal, I went by that. For whatever it’s worth, [JiK’s answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/143556/7734) aligns with one of the red flags in the proposed duplicate. If there is an important distinction to be made here, we can create a new canonical question on how evaluate the reputation of whatever kind of service this is.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft "As the question assumes that the service in question is a journal, I went by that."  That's not assumed in the question, it was asked (before the edit).

Comment: @Roland I don't agree. There are proper conferences send invitations with similar templates, especially for invited talks.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft However, Jik's answer is not a proper answer for this. I don't agree that one simply judge an organization due to their machine-generated templates.

Comment: @Kutadgubilig YMMV, but I prefer to err on the site of caution. If organizers can't be bothered to send a personalized message, I can't be bothered to travel to their conference and give a talk. I get invitations like the one you quote all the time. I'd bet that less than one in fifty is from a reputable conference that I'd even consider to attend. Also, I already know the reputable conferences in my field and don't need to ask about them on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

A human writing to you about your research would say something about your research and say how it contributes to research excellence. Spam bots tend to use a general template and refer to your research in a way that is easy to automate, for example, copy your title in verbatim.

> We are pleased to inform you that Advances in Engineering selection committee identified your paper “Another XYZ” as a key scientific article contributing to research excellence. We would like to write a feature about your paper and highlight it in our next edition of Advances in engineering news series.

This clearly falls to the spam category.

Comment: You'd think so. However, I've received e-mails from reputable journals that start exactly like this.

Comment: @mmeent maybe the reputable journals are also using machine-generated emails? The two aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: There are many reputable organization (conferences/journals) sends machine-generated e-mails.

Comment: @Kutadgubilig Do they ask you to republish existing papers?

Comment: I mean, what reputable conference or journal contacts you simply about a single paper you have already published somewhere else?

Comment: @JiK Read what I have written again!

Comment: @Kutadgubilig Ok, many reputable organizations send machine-generated emails. I agree. Why are you writing this as a comment to this answer?

Answer (score 2):

It is predatory, in the sense that they seek payment for services that are not useful.  It is not, however, a journal.

Comment: What makes you say publicizing one's paper is not useful? There're plenty of reputable venues that do it, e.g. New Scientist, space.com, Physics Today, etc.

Comment: @Allure I didn't say that.  It's not useful publicity.  Physics Today is at least a bit useful.  I don't read the other two.

Comment: The question also didn't say that.

Comment: Well, as it's currently written your answer says "...services that are not useful", which is what led to my comment. If you didn't mean that, might want to edit.